# Latitude/Longitude with no decimals in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps

I have a CSV from my Google Maps timeline and all the lattitude and longitude values look like this (just a string of numbers with no decimals). Is there a way to have QGIS read these values or a field calculator/python expression to add the decimal after the second number? I'm pretty inexperienced and not having much luck finding a solution.

[image: Latitude/longitude values without decimals]

Comment: Given the nines in what would be the tens places for  DMS, it looks like DD without the decimal.  Divide by 10000000 and try it.

Comment: It would be easier for us if you pasted these numbers in as text so we don't have to type them out again with the possibility of error. Also, can you tell us where these points are supposed to be - its possible they are in a coordinate system that isn't lat-long degrees in any way. A clue like that would help *enormously*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This link:

https://www.chipoglesby.com/2018/03/2018-analyzing-google-location-historyII/

explains that the coordinates are lat-long * 1E7 (hence the "E7" designation).

From that web page:

> We can also easily convert latitudeE7 and longitudeE7 by dividing by
> 1e7. 481265044/1e7 becomes 48.1265044 and 116593258/1e7 is 11.6593258
> giving us the coordinates 48.1265044, 11.6593258 which is 48°07'35.4"N
> 11°39'33.6"E.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! I overlooked the E7 and assumed it was code for something else.